# How to align HtmlBody Right-to -Left when sending a cell range using excel VBA via outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, right-to-left

I have a cell range that I need to send via outlook using VBA.

I'm using this code to convert the range to HTML:

```
    Function rangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     FileName:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
rangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
rangetoHTML = Replace(rangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=right x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

And I'm using this code to generate the outlook window with the data I need:

```
Sub Trigger_Email()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim StrBody As String

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
'Only the visible cells in the selection
'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'You can also use a fixed range if you want
Set rng = Range("A1:K42").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next



With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .Subject = Range("D16")
    .HTMLBody = rangetoHTML(rng)
    .Attachments.Add "u:\temp.txt"
    .Display   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The Issue I'm having is that when i'm executing the program, the email that is generated in left-to-right but as my data and design are in Hebrew so it messes-up the email, and for some reason the workbook alignment turns left-to-right as well.

my coding skills in VBA are limited, I spent well over three days researching and trying to solve this myself, and couldn't.
I'l appreciate any help.

Dan.

Comment: Try changing `"align=right x:publishsource="` to `"dir=""rtl"" align=right x:publishsource="`

Comment: it's working. thank you.